# Ring homomorphism and continuous map on prime sprectum

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was trying to solve an exercise from Atiyah-MacDonald on the subject mentioned.

> Let $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $X=Spec(A)$ and $Y=Spec(B)$. If $\mathfrak{q}\in Y$ then $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ is a prime ideal in $A$, i.e. a point of $A$. Thus $\phi$ induces a mapping $\phi^*:Y\rightarrow X$. Show that
>
> 1. If $f\in A$ then ${\phi^*}^{-1}(X_f)=Y_{\phi(f)}$ and hence $\phi^*$ is   continuous.

I tried to verify this by set-theoretic argument, showing LHS is in RHS and vice-versa.

However, I could not understand what is happening in these (middle) set-theoretic arguments, i.e. what they express?

For example, in proving $"\subset"$ for 1, I did this: ($X_f$ is the set of prime ideals of $A$ which do not contain $f$.)

Let $\mathfrak{q}\in {\phi^*}^{-1}(X_f)$.

Then $\phi^*(\mathfrak{q})\in X_f$, i.e. $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})\in X_f$.

That is, $f\notin  \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$.

So $\phi(f)\notin \mathfrak{q}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{q}\in Y_{\phi(f)}$.

But I could not understand what is happening in the topology on $X$ and $Y$ pictorially.

Can one explain what these set-theoretic steps say? i.e. how should one think about solving the problem beyond set-theoretic arguments?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ip}{\mathfrak p} \newcommand{\iq}{\mathfrak q}$This may not be quite what you’re looking for, but I think it might be a useful way of thinking about this issue.

An element $f\in A$ can be thought of as a function on $X$ by defining $f(\ip)$ to be the image of $f$ in the residue field $A_\ip/\ip A_\ip$. (These are “regular functions” on $X$.) Note that this “function” may take values in various different fields, but every field has a unique zero element, so we can at least talk about when $f$ is $0$ and when $f$ is not $0$. Now, $f(\ip)=0$ iff $f\in \ip A_\ip$, which in turn is equivalent to $f\in\ip$. (If $f\in\ip$ then of course $f\in\ip A_\ip$. Conversely, if $f\in \ip A_\ip$, then $f/1 = g/s$ for some $g\in\ip$ and $s\notin\ip$, so $r(fs-g)=0$ for some $r\notin\ip$, so $(sr)f = rg \in\ip$ since $g\in\ip$—but $sr\notin\ip$, so $f\in\ip$ since $\ip$ is prime.) So the points where $f$ is $0$ are precisely the primes $\ip$ of $A$ containing $f$. Geometrically, then, $X_f$ is the set of points of $X$ where $f$ is nonzero.

Now, the ring morphism $\phi$ takes the regular function $f\in A$ on $X$ to the regular function $\phi f\in B$ on $Y$, where $(\phi f)(\iq)$ is again just the image of $\phi f$ in the residue field $B_\iq/\iq B_\iq$. So $\phi$ takes regular functions on $X$ to regular functions on $Y$.

But $\phi$ also gives rise to a map $\phi^*:Y\to X$ given by $\phi^*(\iq) = \phi^{-1}(\iq)$, and this suggests another way to turn regular functions on $X$ (i.e., elements of $A$) into functions on $Y$: given $f\in A$, then we may define $\phi f\in B$ to be the function on $Y$ given by $(\phi f)(\iq) = f(\phi^{*}(\iq))$.

This exercise is essentially asking us to verify that these two definitions of $\phi f$ vanish (or don’t vanish) at the same places: the non-zero set of $\phi f$ in the sense of the first definition is just the $\iq\in Y$ for which $\phi f\notin \iq$, i.e., for which $\iq\in Y_{\phi f}$; and the non-zero set of $\phi f$ in the sense of the second definition is just the set of $\iq\in Y$ for which $\phi^*(\iq)\in X_f$, i.e., for which $\iq\in{\phi^*}^{-1}(X_f)$. Thus, the continuity of $\phi^*$ is equivalent to saying that $\phi^*$ respects the (non-)zero sets of the regular functions on $Y$ and $X$.

Following your set-theoretic steps for one direction, if $\iq\in{\phi^*}^{-1}(X_f)$, then $f(\phi^*(\iq))\neq 0$, so $(\phi f)(\iq)\neq 0$ in the sense of the second definition. Thus $f$ doesn’t vanish at $\phi^{-1}(\iq)$, that is, $f\notin \phi^{-1}(\iq)$. But this means that $\phi(f)\notin \iq$, which in turn says that $(\phi f)(\iq)\neq 0$ (in the sense of the first definition).

(Also, note that this definition of a regular function is not really so strange. If $A=k[x]$ for $k$ algebraically closed, then the only prime ideals are $(0)$ and $(x-a)$ for $a\in k$, so the primes besides $(0)$ correspond to elements of $k$. Moreover, evaluation of some $f\in A$ at $\ip = (x-a)$ corresponds to the traditional evaluation of the polynomial $f$ at $x=a$.)